# Lines appear on the texture in render

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

I am trying to learn Blender. While trying to render a subdivided plane with an image texture applied to it, the subdivision edges are not removed in the rendered result.

Kindly, advise, why these edges appear in the render.

[image: Blender with the object in question]
[image: Blender with the object rendered]
[image: the texture]
[image: Exported UV layout in gimp]

Comment: Yes I agree it looks like they are part of the texture, try to open the image you are using and check if you see those lines outside of blender as well.

Comment: the plane has no modifiers applied to it, the lines appearing during render are added to the texture during the uv unwrap because the plane has been subdivided before the uv unwrap

Comment: Yes those lines appear outside of blender as well

Comment: the exported uv/unwrap image contains these lines

Comment: Then i guess it's a problem of the image itself, you should use a tool like GIMP or Photoshop to delete those lines.

Comment: Does the initial imae, the one you use as a texture, has those lines too? or are they only in the exported UV/unwrap image?

Comment: these lines appear in the exported UV/unwrap image and I didn't remove them while edit using gimp

Comment: I didn't realize that these lines should have been deleted diring edit. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be obvious that a texture with lines in it is going to render with those lines.

The *Export UV Layout* operator exports the UVs as lines so you can use it as a guide for texturing in external programs. (In your question you should not even need it, because you are just texturing a plane.)

[image: plane and UVs]
[image: exported UV layout]
These images are the subdivided plane, its UVs and the image below is the exported UV layout.

In any event you must turn off the UV guide layer in your project (in whatever image editor you are using) before exporting the texture map to use back in blender.